# How do I retrieve data from Firestore using an OR Operator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am attempting to read data from a Firestore collection using the following code:

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
if(user) {
  console.log('User logged in:', user)

db.collection('MediCorePatientUsers').where("GPID", "==", user.email)
.get().then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        renderPatientList(doc);
        })
    })

document.getElementById("nameOfUser").innerHTML = user.email;

} else {
  console.log('User logged out');
}
});
```

This works as intended and displays the correct data to my webpage. However, I would like to add another condition to the code, using an 'or' operator to display data where the field "InsuranceCompany" is also equal to the current user email.

```
db.collection('MediCorePatientUsers').where("GPID", "==", user.email || "InsuranceCompany", "==", user.email)
.get().then((snapshot) => {
snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
    renderPatientList(doc);
    })
})
```

However this is resulting in none of the data displaying when either of the conditions is true. What is incorrect with this code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Cloud Firestore, we can combine multiple `where()` methods to create logical **AND** queries. These queries are called [compound queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries) in the documentation.

However, as indicated in the documentation (Section “[Query Limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations)”):

> Cloud Firestore does not support the following types of queries:
>
> - …
> - **Logical OR queries**. In this case, you should create a separate query for each OR condition and merge the query results in your app.
> - …

---

In order to implement the solution proposed in the documentation, you can do as follows:

```
  const usersRef = db.collection('MediCorePatientUsers');

  async function getMediCorePatientUsers(email) {
    const q1 = usersRef.where("GPID", "==", email).get();
    const q2 = usersRef.where("InsuranceCompany", "==", email).get();

    const [querySnapshot1, querySnapshot2] = await Promise.all([q1, q2]);

    const usersArray1 = querySnapshot1.docs;
    const usersArray2 = querySnapshot2.docs;

    return usersArray1.concat(usersArray2);
  }


  //You can then call the asynchronous getMediCorePatientUsers() function as follows
  auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if(user) {
       getMediCorePatientUsers(user.email).then(result => {
            result.forEach(docSnapshot => {
                renderPatientList(docSnapshot);
            });
       });
    } else {..}
  }
```

This approach is explained in more detail in the following [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-combined-two-firestore-queries-to-simulate-a-logical-or-query-27d28a43cb2d), in particular how to do if you need to de-duplicate the two arrays (usersArray1 and usersArray2). *(disclaimer, I'm the author of the article)*

Comment: Very clear and concise answer, this was the exact solution I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score -3):

You can use as follows

> db.collection('MediCorePatientUsers').where("GPID == " + user.email +
>   " || InsuranceCompany == " + user.email + "")

Comment: This will not work, since the first argument of the [where](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#where) method shall be a string or a  FieldPath.